# What is the proxy for in recaptcha configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, proxy, recaptcha

I am using the recaptcha gem in Rails 3.1.0. I am following the instructions on the github page: https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha

I have acquired the keys and am configuring recaptcha as shown below.

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = '6Lc6BAAAAAAAAChqRbQZcn_yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
  config.private_key = '6Lc6BAAAAAAAAKN3DRm6VA_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  config.proxy = 'http://myproxy.com.au:8080'
end
```

What is the purpose of config.proxy? What should I fill in for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

recaptcha requires web server with outgoing access to the internet. If you'd like to use specific web server for recaptcha, you need its address.

Otherwise, you can just comment it. It should work just fine.

```rb
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = '6Lc6BAAAAAAAAChqRbQZcn_yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
  config.private_key = '6Lc6BAAAAAAAAKN3DRm6VA_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  # config.proxy = 'http://myproxy.com.au:8080'
end
```